# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning WebSocket in NodeJs although implemented on error

Tags: node.js, events, websocket, dns

I'm having issues with a webSocket connection (nodejs, ws). Now and then i see the following error message at the console and i don't know where it comes from. Seems like there is a problem with the internet connection or DNS server at the moment the error is raised. The application should be able to handle broken internet connection. At the moment the error is raised, the whole application stops.

The Error at the console:

```
(node:14656) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Query timed out
at DNS._ontimeoutCheck (C:\Users\XYZ\Documents\nodedev\Server-DEV\node_modules\dns-socket\index.js:123:18)
at Timeout.ontimeoutCheck (C:\Users\XYZ\Documents\nodedev\Server-DEV\node_modules\dns-socket\index.js:53:10)
at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:531:17)
at processTimers (internal/timers.js:475:7)
(node:14656) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Query timed out
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND connect.server.cloud
at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:60:26)
Emitted 'error' event on ServerCloud instance at:
at ServerCloud.<anonymous> (C:\Users\XYZ\Documents\nodedev\Server- 
DEV\plugins\inbound\ks\ks.js:353:18)
at WebSocket.emit (events.js:223:5)
at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (C:\Users\XYZ\Documents\nodedev\Server- 
DEV\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:554:15)
at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:223:5)
at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:406:9)
at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:223:5)
at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:92:8)
at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:60:3)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:81:21) {
errno: 'ENOTFOUND',
code: 'ENOTFOUND',
syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
hostname: 'connect.server.cloud'
```

i have implemented the `.on('error', (err) => {` method in my code:

```
this._ws.on('error', function (error) {
     this.connected = false;
     this.emit('error', error);
     this.LogAtMain('WebSocket Error: ' + error.message);
     console.log('Error message: ' + error.message);
});
```

How can i catch this error unlike implementing the on(error) hook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhere in your code, you forgot to handle a promise rejection. That is why you are getting that error.

You can handle UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning like this:

```
process.on('unhandledRejection', (reason, p) => {
  console.log('Unhandled Rejection at: Promise', p, 'reason:', reason.stack);
  // application specific logging, throwing an error, or other logic here
});
```

Comment: This is a generic handing for the whole process? This would prevent the application from crashing / stopping? I didn't deal with promises in my code that far. I hoped that especially the websocket communication is as easy as consuming all the events.

Comment: Yes, it will receive all unhandledRejection and should prevent app from crashing. You might not create your own promise but maybe a module you are using has promises. Give it a try.